# SlideUp and SlideDown problem in code with div

Tags: jquery

I want to slideUp one div then change background color and then slideDown. I tried like this

```
function show_hide_mode_parameters(color){
    var is_hidden=$('#mode_parameters').is(':hidden');
    if (!is_hidden){
        $('#mode_parameters').slideUp('fast', function() {});
    }
    $('#mode_parameters').css('background-color', color);
    $('#mode_parameters').slideDown('slow', function() {});

}
```

but what happen is when it starts to slideUp immediatelly change background color, like it doesn't execute commands sequantelly . Can someone tell what I make wrong ?

Comment: Can you set how fast you want the div to slide up and down? Maybe it executes the if statement and then moves straight on to the next line of code while it's still animating the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideUp` and `slideDown` gets added to jQuerys animation queue, whereas `css` doesn't.
Which might be why your getting this behavior.

Using the [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method you can add this to the queue.

This should do what you want:

```
function show_hide_mode_parameters(color){

    if ( !$('#mode_parameters').is(':hidden') ) {
        $('#mode_parameters').slideUp('fast');
    }        

    $('#mode_parameters').queue(function(next){
        $(this).css('background-color', color);
        next();
    }).slideDown('slow');      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code needs to run at the end of the `slideUp()`, so use the second argument which is a callback when the animation has finished.

```
function show_hide_mode_parameters(color){
    var is_hidden=$('#mode_parameters').is(':hidden');
    if (!is_hidden){
        $('#mode_parameters').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $('#mode_parameters').css('background-color', color);
            $('#mode_parameters').slideDown('slow');
        });
    }
}
```

Also, `is_hidden` and then `! is_hidden` smells a bit. Why not `is_visible` with `:visible` and then `is_visible`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function show_hide_mode_parameters(color){
    var is_hidden=$('#mode_parameters').is(':hidden');
    if (!is_hidden){
        $('#mode_parameters').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $('#mode_parameters').css('background-color', color);
            $('#mode_parameters').slideDown('slow');
        });
    }

}
```